# ThumbBarButton on IE9

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, internet-explorer-9

i am trying to use the `document.addEventListener('msthumbnailclick', processSelection, false);` method to attach the event to the buttons but i gives me an error

> "Object doesn't support this property
>   or method"

i tried  `document.attachEvent` but it's not working, looks like it doesn't really attach the function to the event

any help ?!!

Comment: Are you sure that you're not in some emulation mode?

Comment: what do u mean ?!! do u mean the same window for example ?

Comment: when i check if ( document.addEventListener ) it returns false :S

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. The Browser Mode was set to IE9 but the Document Mode was set to IE7 Standars. In that case document.addEventListener will be undefined.

To use document.addEventListener you need to be sure to **set the Document Mode to IE9 Standards**.

Press F12 and set it by hand if not already set.

Regards